# Post multiple tagging using Select2, Angular Select UI and Angular-xeditable

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I tired to put multiple select input to my post to tag someone. This is my main target. Therefor i got stuck by following problems. All post update by ajax call to php external file and get all html contains of posts.

I have following JSON data about friends data.

```
$scope.object = {
    "45": {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Orie Cremin",
      "salutation": "",
      "surname": "dolore"
    },
    "46": {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Domenick Blanda",
      "salutation": "",
      "surname": "distinctio"
    },
    "47": {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Zander Wiza",
      "salutation": "",
      "surname": "eos"
    },
    "48": {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Delores Turner",
      "salutation": "",
      "surname": "eum"
    }
  };
```

This JSON will replace to Ajax function according to [this][1]

This is my HTML code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected3" multiple>

        <ui-select-match placeholder="Friends">
          {{$item.value.surname}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item.key as (key, item) in object | filter: $select.search | limitTo:10">
            <div ng-bind-html="item.value.first_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            <div ng-bind-html="item.value.surname | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            <img src="/img/favicon.ico" width="32px" height="32px">
        </ui-select-choices>

</ui-select>
```

I want to know how to get selected values. I want something like this output.

Example: When I selected 45 and 46 data I want to get `[{"Orie Cremin","Domenick Blanda"}]`

I tried to use `{{selected3}}` syntax but data can't get like example output.

Comment: This is my queue to stay away from [`xeditable`](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) as far as humanly possible. It is as [Farfetch'd](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Farfetch'd_(Pokémon)) as that link. Why create html elements that other browsers don't have a clue how to apply anything to it? I'm sorry I don't have anything constructive to say how to resolve the issue, I'm astonished. It looks like a [mcve] but this just go's 1 step behound reading a language. It means you have to know the complete interconnectivity of 1 API implementing another before understanding a code.